# How to compare JSONata performance with jsben.ch or similar tool

Tags: json, jsonata

I am looking for an easy and practical way to compare the performance of different JSONata statements.
I tried [jsben.ch](https://jsben.ch), but it seems not to find the library.

Any suggestion how this could be done easily?

Answer (score 1):

JSBench should be able to work with JSONata with no problems.  In order to load the JSONata library, you can add the following in your "Setup Block", using the CDN URL provided in the [JSONata docs](https://docs.jsonata.org/using-browser):

**Setup Block:**

```
loadLibrary('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js');
```

Then you just need to setup and execute your tests as usual.

Here is an example of a JSONata test that I ran to confirm that it works for this question:

[image: Example JSBench JSONata Test]

**Working Example:** https://jsben.ch/o4VdA

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the test suite mechanism built into JSONata itself:

https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/blob/master/test/test-suite/TESTSUITE.md

Comment: I do not understand. Isn't this used to test the implementation of JSONata in a standardized way? What I like to do is try different JSONata expressions to find out which one performs best. Something like this http://jsben.ch/FQCCo, but I cannot get it to work.